# how to get id of each selected item from two different drop down list using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

how to get id of selected item from two different drop down list. after comparing them if they were same then how to fetch a record from database without reloading a page using ajax and php.

```
<select name="bgnm" id="bg" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getState(this.value);">  <?php
     $dd_res=mysql_query("Select * from building");
     while($r=mysql_fetch_row($dd_res))
     { 
           echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[1] </option>";
     }

 ?> </select> 




 <select name="flat number" id="flat" onChange="getflat(this.value);"> <?php
     $dd_ress=mysql_query("Select * from building");
     while($r=mysql_fetch_row($dd_ress))
     { 
           echo "<option value='$r[2]'> $r[2] </option>";
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: 1.don't use deprecated `mysql_*` library now, switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statmenets` . 2. two times same query for creating same type of drop-down is not right. do query one-time and save values to a variable and use that variable two time to generate two drop-downs

Comment: actually one drop down list for selecting building name and another is for flat no. but that code dosent display sorry for that. i want to compare the id of this two list if they were same then the record will display on same page without reloading a page

Answer (score 0):

You can call getValue() function (as described below) whenever a value changes in any of the dropdown.

```
function getValue() {
var val1=$('bg').val();
var val2=$('flat').val();
if(val1==val2)
{            
     $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url("activeDomain") }}',
            type: 'get',
            //async:true,
            data: {
                id: val1
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {

              //do whatever you wanted to do
            //you can easily manipulate DOM using jQuery
  },
            error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                //in case ajax call error
            }
        });
    }
  }
else{
  //you can send another ajax call
  //use code as above
 }
}
```

Comment: Most welcome. You can accept my answer if it helped you in any way to get to the right solution. ☺

Comment: @Gem I have replied on your post.